# function that return a value from ajax call request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a function that returns a value from an ajax request. I want to stop javascript execution until the function get its value which is return by ajax asynchronous request.
Something like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: 'data to send',
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp;
        },
        error: function () {}
    }); // ajax asynchronus request 
    return data; // return data from the ajax request
}
```

Comment: What does the first A in AJAX stand for?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to register a callback function, something like this:

```
function test() {
    myFunction(function(d) {
        //processing the data
        console.log(d);
    });
}

function myFunction(callback) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: 'data to send',
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp;
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function () {}
    }); // ajax asynchronus request 
    //the following line wouldn't work, since the function returns immediately
    //return data; // return data from the ajax request
}
```

Comment: No need to still store it in `data`. Just call the callback

Comment: @Ian still better than the rest of the kin :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Never said it wasn't :) Just trying to help improve the answer.

Comment: The complete yet concise code of this answer makes js async go 'click'.

Comment: I think the other answers go a little better with what the OP was originally asking. You can make another function that calls the ajax with asyn:false. This way the original method will wait for it. Then set a variable outside of the ajax call, to be set by the anonymous functions within ajax, and return that. function ajaxMethod(){ var returnVal; ajax{....success:  returnVal = value ...error: returnVal = value..}  return returnVal}

Answer (score 15):

Ajax is asynchronous, that means that the ajax call is dispatched but your code keeps on running as happy as before without stopping. Ajax doesn't stop/pause execution until a response is received. You'll have to add an extra callback function or something like that.

```
    function myFunction() {
var data;
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    data: 'data to send',
    async: false,
    success: function (resp) {
        data = resp;
        callback.call(data);
    },
    error: function () {}
}); // ajax asynchronus request 
return data; // return data from the ajax request
  }
```

Comment: You need to actually pass `data` or `resp` to the callback...

Comment: Well, you probably want `callback.call(this, data);` since `call`'s first parameter is for setting the `this` context in the function.

Comment: You also have to define the callback, Else it will give you error,

Answer (score 10):

you need to do asyn = False like :

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    // ...
    success: function(jsonData) {
    //Your Logic
    }
});
```

Comment: That's in case you want an synchronous response, of course.

Comment: `async: false` blocks the user from performing any other action until the ajax finishes.

Answer (score 7):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: 'data to send',
        async: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp;
        },
        error: function () {}
    }); // ajax synchronus request
```

Comment: Synchronous request is deprecated now

Comment: @uniqueNt should i concern with this warning in console

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh yes you should, if you wanna keep the code updated for future

Answer (score 4):

Use `async: false` for your ajax request since Ajax is asynchronous.

Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called. If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

From jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false

Comment: You gotta give a better explanation than that. While that might work, the OP probably won't understand, since they don't understand the problem at hand.